# How to computationally simulate a ball rolling down a curved track?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, centripetal-force

How can I accurately computationally simulate a bowling ball rolling down a bobsleigh track? (Initially ignore air friction and ice/concrete friction.)

I'm familiar with basic Newtonian mechanics, and have written code to simulate basic rigid body interactions before, however I have a hard time understanding how to apply these laws to accurately simulate centripetal/"centrifugal" force, and without an accurate calculation of this force, it would be impossible to find the height the ball would rise to while rolling around a curve.

I also wonder if an accurate measurement of radius of curvature is required to accurately calculate centripetal force. On a bobsleigh track, there is a major axis and a minor axis of curvature, and both these curvatures are changing constantly.

Or is it possible to not know the exact curvature, but simply move the bowling ball forward one timestep, and figure out how far "into the track" the ball would have moved on its current trajectory while passing around a corner, then correct the motion by moving it back out to the surface of the track, and using the required correction distance as an estimate of the curvature of the track and the centripetal force that had to be applied to keep the ball on the surface of the track?

Comment: Do you know how to do it in 2D? With a rolling cylinder down an irregular incline?

Comment: I know how to convert gravitational potential energy into kinetic energy, so I can tell how fast the ball should be moving as a function of height. I want to discount rolling (the eventual goal is to simulate a non-rolling vehicle, like an actual bobsleigh), so I'm not worried about conversion of gravitational potential energy into rotational kinetic energy.

Comment: The bowling ball will fly off the track at the first curve.  THAT is why bobsleds have runners on them which dig into the ice.

Comment: @DavidWhite That's not true. I'm a bobsledder :-) The runners have a rounded cross-section, they don't dig in, and they have very little sideways friction unless under high g-forces. The track is contoured so that the sled should never fly out of the track, which means that in many sections of the track, you're driving 90 degrees from horizontal, up on the wall. If you try to steer hard off a curve too early, you can get pulled up again, sure, but you hit the crash barrier at the top, you don't fly out.
https://www.instagram.com/p/CKE4f1Znq7g

Comment: @LukeHutchison, your key phrase is "if you try to STEER hard off a curve too early".  The ball has no way to steer.

Comment: @DavidWhite Like I said, there is very little sideways friction *unless the sled is under high g-forces*. Of course a ball can't steer, and of course on some curves it will hit the roof. But it totally depends upon the curve. Some curves are designed such that it's physically impossible for any sled ever to hit the roof, no matter how fast you were going, no matter how you enter the curve, and no matter whether you steer at all. That's where I'm saying you were wrong: it's not as simple as "anything that does not steer will hit the roof or fly out of the track". Totally depends on the contour!

Comment: @DavidWhite and obviously a bowling ball will have different motion than a bobsleigh. I don't care for a first approximation. If it hits the roof, I want to simulate that, at least up to the point of collision.

Comment: @LukeHutchison, OK ... NOW you have defined the problem to the degree where you will hopefully get the answer that you are seeking.

Comment: @DavidWhite I haven't changed anything in the definition. I want to roll a bowling ball down the track in simulation, and find (accurately) the path that it takes. If it hits the roof, then it hits the roof (I understand that there are discontinuities that need to be taken into account in simulating inelastic collisions). But I'm not interested in the collisions per se. I am interested in the curved path down the track. Assume that the track is curved such that there's no way for the ball to fly out of the track -- which would be the case with the majority of curves.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a somewhat incomplete answer because there are a lot of unknowns you have to decide for yourself, and regardless there are a lot of ways to answer this question. Some methods will be easier than others, and your final choice largely depends on a combination of what properties you care about simulating and what methods you're comfortable using.

One general method would be to use Hamiltonian mechanics, as it is much easier (in my opinion) to capture constraining forces in that formalism using Lagrange multipliers. You could:

1. Write down the Lagrangian of the ball, along with the constaint equations that define the surface the ball is rolling on.
2. Pass to the Hamiltonian formalism using a Legendre transform, and write down the Hamiltonian equations of motion for the ball.
3. After the last step, you will have a set of first order coupled differential equations which you can solve using your method of choice, such as a Runge-Kutta 4th order method.

This is a very rough outline, but there's no single way to answer this question, and, like I said, a lot will depend on your current knowledge and comfort with different techniques. I might suggest as well starting small and simulating the same problem in a lower dimension - perhaps try to simulate a ball rolling on a half pipe first to get the general idea.